# Authentication for NAV Web Services with Windows User over HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I have a NAV instance which exposes (OData) Web Services and [is configured to use `Windows` as the credential type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/users-and-credential-types).  I am able to authenticate against these Web Services successfully with [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager).  However, I would prefer to use HTTP basic authentication to authenticate against the service.  I understand that [one can create an Access Key for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/how-to--use-an-access-key-for-soap-and-odata-web-service-authentication).  I understand that if I set the Basic Authentication Username to the `User Name` and the password to the `Web Service Access Key` from the NAV User Card, I should be able to use Basic HTTP Authentication.  I have done this successfully on other NAV instances that are configured to use the `NavUserPassword` credential type.  However, this doesn't work for the instance with `Windows` credential type.

More specifically, if I request a protected resource from the `NavUserPassword` instance, I recieve a 401 with a [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header with value `Basic realm=""`.  If I do the same with the `Windows` instance, I get a `WWW-Authenticate` header with value `NTLM`.  This suggests that it's not a simple case of providing the wrong password but a more complicated case of the NAV instance not being configured to accept any Web Service Access Keys.

[The documentation on `Web Services Authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/web-services-authentication) seems to imply that for Windows credential type, HTTP Basic Authentication for Web Services is not possible, but that isn't very explicit and I'm not sure if I am parsing the documentation correctly.

As an aside, the above documentation suggests that OAuth may also be used as an authentication mechanism but the linked documentation is behind a PartnerSource portal wall.  If HTTP Basic Authentication isn't an option in my case, is OAuth an option?

Answer (score 3):

I haven’t tried myself, but as it’s said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/users-and-credential-types)

> All users of a Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server instance must be using
>   the same credential type. You specify which credential type is used
>   for a particular Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server instance in the
>   Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server Administration tool.

So you can’t authenticate user with NavPassword if the instance is configured for ntlm. But you always can have separate instance (= service tier) installed and configured for another credentials type.

You can also restrict regular RTC users from connecting that instance at all and make it dedicated to web services.

**Upd**

As I've already mentioned [service tier](https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/w/navdev/97/dynamics-nav-role-tailored-architecture) is the same as Nav instance. One can find out how to create new nav instance from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/how-to--create-a-microsoft-dynamics-nav-server-instance). The difference between instances will be in the URL to access them. Different instances can be located on separate servers as well as on the same one.

In terms of MS Windows Nav instance is a service.

Comment: I guess the idea in this answer that I don't feel is fully supported is that NavPassword is synonymous with web service access token usage since one can create a web service access token for a Windows user.

That being said, I think the ultimate answer to my question relies on service tiers and someone who provides an answer explaining what a service tier is and how one can be added along side an exisitng service tier would likely have their answer accepted as correct.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible, the steps are

1. You'll need a Service Tier using NavUserPassword Auth (for this you'll need a certificate)
2. In NAV you need to create a new user and generate a Web Service Key for it
3. Using the Username and the Key you can use Basic Auth

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/web-services-authentication

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the Service Tier part? That part seems to be missing from my knowledge and the link you provided does not elaborate on that concept.

Comment: Keep in mind, the OData service already exists and can be accessed via NTLM which makes it feel like a Service Tier already exists.

Comment: Hi, you'll need to add a second Service Tier instance what is using a different Authentication Method